# appendChild xml c++ not working as needed

Tags: c++, xml, msdn

Why, after doing `appendChild`, I can't read the next node?

```
(newChildList->get_item(count,&pNewChild))
```

The `appendChild`  API is not working  as it should be. After I put this line, I am not able to get the next `get_item()` in the loop. It returns `pNewChild` which is `NULL`. Why does this happen?

```
IXMLDOMNode *pNewChild=NULL,*outNewChild;
IXMLDOMNodeList *newChildList=NULL;
BSTR newName;
long len=0;
HRESULT hr=S_OK;

//aggregate attribute
//CHK_HR(aggregateAttribute(pNodeNew,pXMLDomSrc,pXMLDomNew));

//read the list of child
CHK_HR(pNodeNew->get_childNodes(&newChildList));
CHK_HR(newChildList->get_length(&len));
//go over all the children
for(long count=0;count<len;count++)
{       
    hr =newChildList->get_item(count,&pNewChild);
    CHK_HR(pNewChild->get_nodeName(&newName));

    USES_CONVERSION;
    string temp= W2T(newName);
    temp = temp.substr(temp.find_first_of("/:")+1);
    if (!temp.compare("tuple")) 
    {       
        //CHK_HR(aggregateTuple(pXMLDomSrc,pNewChild));
    }       
    else 
    {       
        CHK_HR(pXMLElement->appendChild(pNewChild,&outNewChild));
    }
    SAFE_RELEASE(pNewChild);
    //SysFreeString(newName);
}

CleanUp:
//SAFE_RELEASE(newChildList);
SAFE_RELEASE(pNewChild);
return hr;
```

Answer (score 2):

appendChild moves the node elsewhere, reducing the child list by one each time.

Try this :

```
// reverse loop from index base 0 "len-1" to 0
for(long count=len-1;count>=0;--count)
```

On a side note, you leak lots of memory (`outNewChild` and `newName`)